# Linux web hosting server 100% even after deleting files

Tags: linux, ssh

My GoDaddy Red Hat Fedora Core 7 virtual private server won't let me make MySQL database backups anymore, because it reports being 100% of capacity. I have deleted files and it still won't report less than 100%. And even worse, I cant restart the server when it is that full.

I have to use SSH to administer all of this and I am not so strong in that area. So I have all of these things I googled and tried, but I don't fully understand them and how they can resolve my issue. Here are a list of the commands I tried. If you have questions about what results I got or how I can use them better, I would greatly appreciate the input.

```
sudo rm -Rf ~/.Trash/*<br>
tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda3<br>
lsof|grep delete<br>
lsof | grep log$<br>
lsof +L1<br>
```

I did use this command to find that these locations appear to be huge, even reporting larger than the 10GB capacity.

```
du -sh ./*  

./lib is 1.3gb
./log is 7.6gb
./spool is 1.6gb
./maillog.l is 6.1gb
```

Comment: Rotate your log files. Absolutely no reason you need to have nearly 8 GB worth of logs on your server.  If you do have a requirement to keep the logs, then add more storage to your server, storage does the server have exactly?

Answer (score 2):

If your disk is at 100%, deleting small files probably won't help because of the stuff in memory which is waiting to be written to disk. Also, when you are at > 95% usage some things may not be able to write to disk because its often reserved for Superuser.

That said, the cause of your problem is clear - lack of maintenance.   If you are not worried about older log information, you should be able to go into the log directory and "rm *gz" (but check first) - this should delete any old compressed logs compressed with gzip.  If you are desperate, and don't care for the contents and the above does not work, (as root) "rm log/*; systemctl restart rsyslog" will delete everything in the log directory and restart logging, giving you quite a bit of space.

You should similarly explore the maillog.I directory and delete it if its safe to do so.  If you are unsure.

That said, everything you have written indicates you don't have the skill to maintain a Linux server at the console, and you should really learn about the Linux command line - anything you do -if you don't know the basics - can make your life worse.

Once you have basic linux skills, get logrotate to automatically rotate your log files, and put in some kind of monitoring system to check the basics (like disk space, cpu load) to report back before it becomes a crisis.